# Parsing multidimensional array value

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

Hello I have the following array response, printed from $response.

```
Array ( [ret_code] => 0 [ret_msg] => OK [ext_code] => [ext_info] => [result] => Array ( [BIT] => Array ( [equity] => 0 [available_balance] => 0 [used_margin] => 0 [order_margin] => 0 [position_margin] => 0 [occ_closing_fee] => 0 [occ_funding_fee] => 0 [wallet_balance] => 0 [realised_pnl] => 0 [unrealised_pnl] => 0 [cum_realised_pnl] => 0 [given_cash] => 0 [service_cash] => 0 ) [BTC] => Array ( [equity] => 0 [available_balance] => 0 [used_margin] => 0 [order_margin] => 0 [position_margin] => 0 [occ_closing_fee] => 0 [occ_funding_fee] => 0 [wallet_balance] => 0 [realised_pnl] => 0 [unrealised_pnl] => 0 [cum_realised_pnl] => 0 [given_cash] => 0 [service_cash] => 0 ) [DOT] => Array ( [equity] => 0 [available_balance] => 0 [used_margin] => 0 [order_margin] => 0 [position_margin] => 0 [occ_closing_fee] => 0 [occ_funding_fee] => 0 [wallet_balance] => 0 [realised_pnl] => 0 [unrealised_pnl] => 0 [cum_realised_pnl] => 0 [given_cash] => 0 [service_cash] => 0 ) [EOS] => Array ( [equity] => 0 [available_balance] => 0 [used_margin] => 0 [order_margin] => 0 [position_margin] => 0 [occ_closing_fee] => 0 [occ_funding_fee] => 0 [wallet_balance] => 0 [realised_pnl] => 0 [unrealised_pnl] => 0 [cum_realised_pnl] => 0 [given_cash] => 0 [service_cash] => 0 ) [ETH] => Array ( [equity] => 0 [available_balance] => 0 [used_margin] => 0 [order_margin] => 0 [position_margin] => 0 [occ_closing_fee] => 0 [occ_funding_fee] => 0 [wallet_balance] => 0 [realised_pnl] => 0 [unrealised_pnl] => 0 [cum_realised_pnl] => 0 [given_cash] => 0 [service_cash] => 0 ) [USDT] => Array ( [equity] => 100.37284639 [available_balance] => 99.93706749 [used_margin] => 0.6676989 [order_margin] => 0 [position_margin] => 0.6676989 [occ_closing_fee] => 3.0E-7 [occ_funding_fee] => 0 [wallet_balance] => 115.60476639 [realised_pnl] => -0.0246807 [unrealised_pnl] => -0.23192 [cum_realised_pnl] => -13.21663361 [given_cash] => 0 [service_cash] => 0 ) [XRP] => Array ( [equity] => 0 [available_balance] => 0 [used_margin] => 0 [order_margin] => 0 [position_margin] => 0 [occ_closing_fee] => 0 [occ_funding_fee] => 0 [wallet_balance] => 0 [realised_pnl] => 0 [unrealised_pnl] => 0 [cum_realised_pnl] => 0 [given_cash] => 0 [service_cash] => 0 ) ) [time_now] => 1647873404.584141 [rate_limit_status] => 119 [rate_limit_reset_ms] => 1647873404572 [rate_limit] => 120 )
```

And I'm trying to parse the [available_balance] value of => 99.93706749

I've tried $response[0]['result']['USDT']['available_balance']... and several iterations/combinations. How may I successfully parse this value? Do I need to use json_decode?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try with `$response['result']['USDT']['available_balance']`